# Firebase authorisation

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

```
mAuth?.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val user = User(fullName, age, email)
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
                .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener { childTask ->
                    if (childTask.isSuccessful) {
                        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_registrationWindow_to_loginWindow)
                        showToast("User has been registered successfully")
                    } else {
                        showToast("Failed to register! Try again!")
                    }
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                }
        } else {
            showToast("Failed to register! Try again!")
        }
    }
progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
```

I'm trying to check in the second `addOnCompleteListener` the condition of operation, but the second block of `addOnCompleteListener` isn't called. And I don't have any mistakes, the user is added to database, but block isn't called.

Comment: I mean the line:  ".setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener { childTask ->"

Comment: Is any of the `showToast("User has been registered successfully")` or `showToast("Failed to register! Try again!")` triggered? If you try to log the value of `user.getEmail()` for example in the fist database call, are you getting something printed out?

Answer (score 0):

Is it redirecting to different fragment though? according to your logic, it may not show if it is redirecting to different screen before displaying toast, I would also suggest you try use Log instead of Toast and check in the Logcat for any errors you might have missed out,or in general debug using the Logcat as toasts can mess up when there is threads and may not show, also if you are testing on an emulator sometimes Toasts don't show, check on a real device and see if you still face the problem